# Cement around decorative bricks leaves grey/matte coating on bricks

Tags: brick

I'm installing a decorative brick wall (individual thin bricks) for the first time. I glued all the bricks and now I'm working on the cement (mortar) around the bricks. I did a few rows yesterday for a test. While applying the mortar, some fell on the bricks. I wiped the bricks with a dry cloth as much as I could but the bricks are now covered with a thin "coating" that makes them pale and matte.

Q1: How can I clean the bricks?

Q2: How should I work the rest of the wall to avoid that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Q1:

I would try a stiff brush and water.  If this does not work, you may be able to try a muriatic acid solution, but I would look at the manufacturer's recommendations first.  Depending on the brick color and type, this may discolor the brick.

Q2:

- Apply the grout using a [grout bag](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0039SLV9Y) to minimize the mess.
- When the joints are filled, wait until the grout is the consistency of wet beach sand.
- Go over the joints with a [brick jointer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000BYE3L).
- As you are jointing, periodically wipe down the brick surface with a wet [mason's sponge](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000I19GY2) to remove any grout from the brick face (clean the sponge out in a bucket of water as you go).

Comment: Muriatic acid is very effective.

Answer (score 1):

After you finish, but before it cures, try powerwashing them.  Start with low pressue or back up a ways at first to make sure you dont ruin the new mortar, then move closer or increase as you can.

Comment: This is an indor wall.